# couchdb : Depends: couchdb-bin (>= 1.6.1-0ubuntu4) broken packages

Tags: apt, dependencies, couchdb, held-packages

I encountered a problem trying to install couchdb on my Ubuntu 14.10 (GNU/Linux 3.10.23-xxxx-std-ipv6-64 x86_64) server.

When I run  apt-get install couchdb,

I've got the following mistakes :

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies.
     couchdb : Depends: couchdb-bin (>= 1.6.1-0ubuntu4) 
     but it is not going     to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I followed a lot of steps found on the net to try to fix it, but nothing worked...

I hope someone will be able to find out what's going wrong...

Thanks

EDIT:

Here are the steps I have already done :

- I tried to use Aptitude, but it installed Couchdb 1.0.1 instead of 1.6.1
- I tried to remove completely the installation using "apt-get remove couchdb couchdb-bin erlang-base erlang-base-hipe erlang-solutions" But the result was the same.
- The problem occurs when I add the PPA of couchdb to install the last version. If I remove the .plist, installation works, but it installs the 1.0.1 version.
- I tried all the possible solutions to update apt-get or to clean it...

Do you think that if I update my Ubuntu 14.10 to 15 it could fix the problem ?

Comment: Could you be specific about what steps you have already tried? Otherwise people are likely going to suggest things you know don't work. On that note, have you tried using `aptitude`?

Comment: @TheSchwa, I edited my question, thank you for the remark.

Comment: According to [Launchpad](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/utopic/+source/couchdb) the `couchdb` version for Utopic is `1.6.0-0ubuntu4`. On my 15.10 installation, the package `couchdb` is version `1.6.0-0ubuntu7`. So neither of those meet the requirement `(>= 1.6.1-0ubuntu4)`. It sounds like a broken dependency. See if either of [the solution to this answer](http://askubuntu.com/q/696930/205638) work.

Comment: As I precised, I already tried both answers which are given in this post... :(

Comment: I have this problem too (for a long time).

Answer (score 0):

Updating my Ubuntu release worked (I upgraded it from 14 to 15.10 doing do-release-upgrade). 
Now I was able to install 1.6.0 couchdb version. Still have to look for installing the 1.6.1.